# SharePoint - GetURLKeyValue in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, sharepoint

Using SharePoint's `GetUrlKeyValue()` function easily retrieves URL query strings and could be used in Javascript and AngularJS without modification. 
However, by upgrading to Angular 2+ (specifically 5), using this function results in an error in my IDE (Atom):

> Cannot find name 'GetUrlKeyValue'.

I was able to convert SharePoint's `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()` function to work with Angular 2+ by using `window.parent['SP'].UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()`, however, prepending `window.parent['SP']` has not resulted in any success.

How can I use this SharePoint built-in function in Angular 2+?

Comment: Have you tried ```window.parent['GetUrlKeyValue']()``` or ```window.parent['SP'].GetUrlKeyValue()```?

Comment: `window.parent['GetUrlKeyValue']()` worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you got angular working by embedding it in an iframe. The functions and objects provided by sharepoint are not directly available to you in angular. But you can access all by referencing the parent window object.

So if you used the `GetUrlKeyValue()` function before, you have to use `window.parent.GetUrlKeyValue()` or `window.parent['GetUrlKeyValue']()` instead.